# php images compare with existing blob field

Tags: php, image, compare

In PHP, Can we compare two images to check if the are similar? not size but pattern.
I have found one class "image.compare.class.php" In http://www.phpclasses.org/ 
but it is not helping.

Multiple images are already upload in databse having datatype Blob. When I upload new image it should select all added images and compare with new image. If already added, it should display message. The images are clothes Pattern. so size may change but basic patter will be same. How to check that ??
Please help

Answer (score 0):

[ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compareimages.php) may be a solution but the negative is that the documentation for this library is almost zero, so that errors and many tests will be presented